# ExtJS - Stripe rows does not work with PreviewPlugin after upgrading to 4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I'm upgrading a grid that uses the PreviewPlugin extension from ExtJS 4.1 to 4.2.  After upgrading, the `stripeRows` config option no longer works correctly.  Is this just a bug or am I doing something wrong?

PreviewPlugin + stripeRows, ExtJS 4.1.1 (works): http://jsfiddle.net/7H84g/2/

No PreviewPlugin + stripeRows, ExtJS 4.2.0 (works): http://jsfiddle.net/WUeWb/1/

PreviewPlugin + stripeRows, ExtJS 4.2.0 (does not work): http://jsfiddle.net/94xhs/

Comment: Did you update the style sheet (and not just the .js file)?  This has burned me in the past

Comment: Good idea but there is no css for that plugin.  I did update ext-all.css to the appropriate version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your extjs overrides file:

```
//////////////////////////////
// Ext.grid.feature.RowWrap //
//////////////////////////////
/**
 * Fixed stripeRows not working on wrapped rows
 */
Ext.override(Ext.grid.feature.RowWrap, {
    wrapTpl: [
        '<tr data-boundView="{view.id}" data-recordId="{record.internalId}" data-recordIndex="{recordIndex}" class="{[values.itemClasses.join(" ")]} {[values.rowClasses.join(" ")]} ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-wrap-row">',
            '<td class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-rowwrap ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-td" colSpan="{columns.length}">',
                '<table class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + '{view.id}-table ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">',
                    '{[values.view.renderColumnSizer(out)]}',
                    '{%',
                        'values.itemClasses.length = 0;',
                        'this.nextTpl.applyOut(values, out, parent)',
                    '%}',
                '</table>',
            '</td>',
        '</tr>', {
            priority: 200
        }
    ]
});
```

This is just a copy/paste by adding `{[values.rowClasses.join(" ")]}` in the original tpl.